# "match" compiles into suboptimal asm compared to "if/else"

Tags: performance, rust

Consider the following binary search tree node:

```rust
pub struct Node {
    key: i64,
    left_ptr: Option<Box<Node>>,
    right_ptr: Option<Box<Node>>,
}
```

Here are two implementations of "contains" method with identical behavior:

```rust
pub fn contains_match(root: &Option<Box<Node>>, key: i64) -> bool {
    let mut node_ptr = root;
    while let Some(node) = node_ptr {
        match node.key.cmp(&key) {
            Ordering::Equal => return true,
            Ordering::Less => node_ptr = &node.right_ptr,
            Ordering::Greater => node_ptr = &node.left_ptr,
        }
    }
    false
}

pub fn contains_if_else(root: &Option<Box<Node>>, key: i64) -> bool {
    let mut node_ptr = root;
    while let Some(node) = node_ptr {
        if node.key == key {
            return true;
        }
        if node.key < key {
            node_ptr = &node.right_ptr;
        } else {
            node_ptr = &node.left_ptr;
        }
    }
    false
}
```

However, the ASM code they translate into differs significantly:

```
playground::contains_match:
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    je  .LBB0_7
    movq    $-1, %rcx

.LBB0_2:
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    cmpq    %rsi, (%rax)
    setne   %dl
    cmovlq  %rcx, %rdx
    cmpq    $-1, %rdx
    je  .LBB0_5
    movb    $1, %al
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je  .LBB0_8
    movq    (%rdi), %rdi
    addq    $8, %rdi
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    jne .LBB0_2
    jmp .LBB0_7

.LBB0_5:
    movq    (%rdi), %rdi
    addq    $16, %rdi
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    testq   %rax, %rax
    jne .LBB0_2

.LBB0_7:
    xorl    %eax, %eax

.LBB0_8:
    retq
```

```
playground::contains_if_else:
    cmpq    $0, (%rdi)
    je  .LBB1_5

.LBB1_2:
    movq    (%rdi), %rdi
    movq    (%rdi), %rax
    cmpq    %rsi, %rax
    je  .LBB1_3
    leaq    16(%rdi), %rcx
    addq    $8, %rdi
    cmpq    %rsi, %rax
    cmovlq  %rcx, %rdi
    cmpq    $0, (%rdi)
    jne .LBB1_2

.LBB1_5:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    retq

.LBB1_3:
    movb    $1, %al
    retq
```

[Playground.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=af2006eb9dc75f2d5c15726a42613665)

According to my benchmarks, the "match" version is 15 to 25% slower then then the "if/else" version:

```
100k_random_lookup_hits/contains_if_else                                                                            
                        time:   [14.096 ms 14.146 ms 14.212 ms]
100k_random_lookup_hits/contains_match                                                                            
                        time:   [17.938 ms 17.961 ms 17.991 ms]

100k_random_lookup_misses/contains_if_else                                                                            
                        time:   [20.451 ms 20.475 ms 20.502 ms]
100k_random_lookup_misses/contains_match                                                                            
                        time:   [23.900 ms 23.920 ms 23.943 ms]
```

[Benchmarks.](https://github.com/vnetserg/bst_bench/blob/main/benches/benches.rs)

Is there a reason why the "match" version is compiled into a slower asm?

Comment: What test data are you using for the benchmark? Can you post your benchmark code?

Comment: What happens if you replace `Ordering::Less/Greater` with a simple `_  => {}`?

Comment: Added benchmarks code to the question: https://github.com/vnetserg/bst_bench/blob/main/benches/benches.rs

Comment: Here's a more minimal example that compiles down to different ASM: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/ca9Msc4sn

Comment: Thanks to @sebpuetz 's godbold link, here is a variation that tries to isolate the *problematic* case:  https://rust.godbolt.org/z/TeM1Gr4W1 (however, I have no clue about the reason why it behaves like this).

Comment: Regarding order being important, there's some inline comment [in the source of cmp impl for ints](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/cmp.rs.html#1271-1277) linking to a [Github issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63758), so I think that's a different thing that you ran into!

Comment: @sebpuetz thanks for the information, I agree with you, this is a different thing but since the `match` statement relies on `cmp()`, the suboptimal asm generation observed with `match` may simply be the consequence of what has been observed about `cmp()`.

Answer (score 1):

So this would be a problem with LLVM, not Rust specifically, since it seems like for whatever reason the switch expression isn't getting optimized correctly.

```
switch i8 %_6.0, label %bb4 [
    i8 -1, label %bb6
    i8 0, label %bb9
    i8 1, label %bb3
  ], !dbg !22
```

I spent a long time playing with it on godbolt. Couldn't figure out why but it seems this has been an issue for quite a while. From what I can tell, match is still better in most cases but this does happen, particularly with a small number of branches like this.

https://llvm.org/pubs/2007-05-31-Switch-Lowering.html

https://llvm.org/devmtg/2015-10/slides/Wennborg-SwitchLowering.pdf